# Expo/react-native what are the databases that can be integrated together in crossplatform apps

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo, cross-platform, create-react-native-app

i have tested **watermelon db** it **didnt** worked well gave too many errors,
tested **pouch** had some problem with **adapter settings**
also tested realm and it also gave alot of bugs,
trying to use sqlite but now before testing something new , just want to ask others what databases can be integrate together to run a app on both ios and android without having to face much of headache, also i have searched on web and youtube no specific answers if there are they are too old like before 2020 or just irreleavant to current react/npm versions
**my os: debian based Parrot os
node: 18**
target-platform : android|ios|web

just a stable db which is fast , reliable and can be set up easily and can work offline

I apologize first hand but i have spent whole week on just errors and bugs so if you can help me out or just have a good options i will be happy to hear it,,